# How to / Best way to create a new column in a df if a column contains string from a list using lower casing for both

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Say I have a df with the following: cf_key is the list, CF_ref is where I would like the value of cf_key to go. So for example I would like to check if df[Operating_Activity].lower() is in cf_key.lower() and if so append cf_key to CF_ref.

So Net income.lower() is in cf_key.lower() and therefore CF_ref[1] should == "Net Income".

I cant get this to work and have exhausted all the methods I have found so far on the SO.

```
   CF_ref                                 Operating_Activity  Dec. 31, 2010  Dec. 31, 2009  Dec. 31, 2008                                          cf_key
0     NaN                               Operating activities            NaN            NaN            NaN                                      Net Income
1     NaN                                         Net income        78716.0        52810.0       110316.0                   Depreciation and Amortization
2     NaN  Adjustments to reconcile net income to net cas...            NaN            NaN            NaN                           Deferred Income Taxes
3     NaN  Income from discontinued operations, net of in...            NaN            NaN        -5784.0                        Stock Based Compensation
4     NaN                      Depreciation and amortization        27728.0        24905.0        24638.0                            Other Non-Cash Items
5     NaN  Gain on disposal of discontinued operations, n...            NaN            NaN       -44127.0                       Change In Working Capital
6     NaN                    Provision for doubtful accounts           40.0          516.0           72.0            Cash Provided By Operating Activites
7     NaN                              Deferred income taxes         2662.0          573.0        -5714.0                    Tangible Capital Expenditure
8     NaN  Excess tax benefits from stock based compensation         -759.0         -225.0         -375.0                  Intangible Capital Expenditure
```

Comment: what did you try ? Show your code ? did you try to us `df.apply()` ? You could create minimal working code with data which we could run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `df.apply(function, axis=1)`or `df['Operating_Activity'].apply(function)` you can run function for every row and this function can compare item from this row with full  `df["cf_key"]` and return `df['Operating_Activity']` or `NaN` which you can assigned to column `df['CF_ref']`

```
def convert(row):
    if any(row['Operating_Activity'].lower() == df['cf_key'].str.lower()):
        return row['Operating_Activity']
    else:
        return row['CF_ref']

df['CF_ref'] = df.apply(convert, axis=1)
```

or

```
def convert(item):
    if any(item.lower() == df['cf_key'].str.lower()):
        return item
    else:
        return np.NaN #'NaN'

df['CF_ref'] = df['Operating_Activity'].apply(convert)
```

---

Minimal working code

```
text = '''   CF_ref                                 Operating_Activity  Dec. 31, 2010  Dec. 31, 2009  Dec. 31, 2008                                          cf_key
0     NaN                               Operating activities            NaN            NaN            NaN                                      Net Income
1     NaN                                         Net income        78716.0        52810.0       110316.0                   Depreciation and Amortization
2     NaN  Adjustments to reconcile net income to net cas...            NaN            NaN            NaN                           Deferred Income Taxes
3     NaN  Income from discontinued operations, net of in...            NaN            NaN        -5784.0                        Stock Based Compensation
4     NaN                      Depreciation and amortization        27728.0        24905.0        24638.0                            Other Non-Cash Items
5     NaN  Gain on disposal of discontinued operations, n...            NaN            NaN       -44127.0                       Change In Working Capital
6     NaN                    Provision for doubtful accounts           40.0          516.0           72.0            Cash Provided By Operating Activites
7     NaN                              Deferred income taxes         2662.0          573.0        -5714.0                    Tangible Capital Expenditure
8     NaN  Excess tax benefits from stock based compensation         -759.0         -225.0         -375.0                  Intangible Capital Expenditure'''

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

# --- read data ---

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s{2,}')

#df['lower_cf_key'] = df['cf_key'].str.lower()
#print(df['lower_cf_key'])

# --- function #1 ---

def convert(row):
    #if any(row['Operating_Activity'].lower() == df['lower_cf_key']):
    if any(row['Operating_Activity'].lower() == df['cf_key'].str.lower()):
        return row['Operating_Activity']
    else:
        return row['CF_ref']

df['CF_ref'] = df.apply(convert, axis=1)

print(df['CF_ref'])

# --- function #2 ---

def convert(item):
    if any(item.lower() == df['cf_key'].str.lower()):
        return item
    else:
        return np.NaN #'NaN'

df['CF_ref'] = df['Operating_Activity'].apply(convert)

print(df['CF_ref'])
```

Result for `df["CF_ref"]`

```
0                              NaN
1                       Net income
2                              NaN
3                              NaN
4    Depreciation and amortization
5                              NaN
6                              NaN
7            Deferred income taxes
8                              NaN
Name: CF_ref, dtype: object
```

---

**EDIT:**

I don't know why you keep it in column `cf_key`. I would create separated dictionary for this:

```
data = {
    'net income': 'Net income',
    'deferred income taxes': 'Deferred income taxes',
    'revenue': 'Revenue',
    'net sales': 'Revenue', 
    'depreciation': 'Depreciation and Amortization',
    'amortization': 'Depreciation and Amortization',
    'amortisation': 'Depreciation and Amortization',
    'depreciation and amortisation': 'Depreciation and Amortization',
    'depreciation and amortization': 'Depreciation and Amortization',
}
    
def convert(item):
    return data.get(item.lower(), np.NaN)
```

or

```
data = {
    'Net income': [
        'net income',
    ],
    'Deferred income taxes': [
        'deferred income taxes',
    ],
    'Revenue': [
        'revenue',
        'net sales',
    ],
    'Depreciation and amortization': [
        'depreciation',
        'amortization',
        'amortisation',
        'depreciation and amortisation',
        'depreciation and amortization',
    ],
}

def convert(item):
    for key, values in data.items():
        if item.lower() in values:
            return key
        
    return np.NaN
```

Minimal working example

```
text = '''   CF_ref                                 Operating_Activity  Dec. 31, 2010  Dec. 31, 2009  Dec. 31, 2008                                          cf_key
0     NaN                               Operating activities            NaN            NaN            NaN                                      Net Income
1     NaN                                         Net income        78716.0        52810.0       110316.0                   Depreciation and Amortization
2     NaN  Adjustments to reconcile net income to net cas...            NaN            NaN            NaN                           Deferred Income Taxes
3     NaN  Income from discontinued operations, net of in...            NaN            NaN        -5784.0                        Stock Based Compensation
4     NaN                      Depreciation and amortization        27728.0        24905.0        24638.0                            Other Non-Cash Items
5     NaN  Gain on disposal of discontinued operations, n...            NaN            NaN       -44127.0                       Change In Working Capital
6     NaN                    Provision for doubtful accounts           40.0          516.0           72.0            Cash Provided By Operating Activites
7     NaN                              Deferred income taxes         2662.0          573.0        -5714.0                    Tangible Capital Expenditure
8     NaN  Excess tax benefits from stock based compensation         -759.0         -225.0         -375.0                  Intangible Capital Expenditure
9     NaN                                            Revenue         -759.0         -225.0         -375.0                  Intangible Capital Expenditure
10    NaN                                          Net Sales         -759.0         -225.0         -375.0                  Intangible Capital Expenditure'''

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

# --- read data ---

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s{2,}')

#df['lower_cf_key'] = df['cf_key'].str.lower()
#print(df['lower_cf_key'])

# --- function #1 ---

data = {
    'net income': 'Net income',
    'deferred income taxes': 'Deferred income taxes',
    'revenue': 'Revenue',
    'net sales': 'Revenue', 
    'depreciation': 'Depreciation and Amortization',
    'amortization': 'Depreciation and Amortization',
    'amortisation': 'Depreciation and Amortization',
    'depreciation and amortisation': 'Depreciation and Amortization',
    'depreciation and amortization': 'Depreciation and Amortization',
}

def convert(item):
    return data.get(item.lower(), np.NaN)

df['CF_ref'] = df['Operating_Activity'].apply(convert)

print(df['CF_ref'])


# --- function #2---

data = {
    'Net income': [
        'net income',
    ],
    'Deferred income taxes': [
        'deferred income taxes',
    ],
    'Revenue': [
        'revenue',
        'net sales',
    ],
    'Depreciation and amortization': [
        'depreciation',
        'amortization',
        'amortisation',
        'depreciation and amortisation',
        'depreciation and amortization',
    ],
}

def convert(item):
    for key, values in data.items():
        if item.lower() in values:
            return key
        
    return np.NaN

df['CF_ref'] = df['Operating_Activity'].apply(convert)

print(df['CF_ref'])
```

Comment: How would I adapt this going forwards to include several items in cf_key such as "Revenue", "Net Sales" etc to return just "Revenue" essentially synonyms. Another example would be "depreciation", "amortization", "amortisation", "depreciation and amortisation", "depreciation and amortization" for all of these I would want the cf_ref to return "Depreciation and Amortization"

Comment: you would need some dictionary for this (instead of column `cf_key`) - ie. `{'revenue': 'Revenue', 'net sales': 'Revenue', ...}`  and search in this dictionary.